# In SQL Server syspolicy_purge_history job step 3 failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-job

SQL server syspolicy_purge_history job step 3 failed due to below error. Is any one faced same kind of issue while run this step#3?

**Error Log:**

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Unhandled
>   Exception:System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Management.Automation.dll' or one of its dependencies. Access
>   is denied.     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.SqlPowerShell.Main(String[]
>   args).  Process Exit Code 255.  The step failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with the server. Server manager dashboard not opening and displaying "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation.dll' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied" error message in the window.

Issue with the loading System.Management.Automation.dll.